Questions on treemap in r studio
I have a question on the treemap package in r studio. After implementing install.packages("treemap"), the treemap cannot be included through library. It informs that Error in library(treemap) : there is no treemap pakcage. Why doed this happen? Is it due to the version of the r studio (2022.07.1 Build 554). The install information is as follows:
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
将程序包安装入‘C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(因为‘lib’没有被指定)
还安装相依关系‘htmltools’, ‘sass’, ‘bslib’, ‘shiny’


  有二进制版本的，但源代码版本是后来的:
          binary  source needs_compilation
htmltools  0.5.5 0.5.8.1              TRUE
sass       0.4.5   0.4.9              TRUE
bslib      0.4.2   0.7.0             FALSE
shiny      1.7.4 1.8.1.1             FALSE
treemap    2.4-3   2.4-4             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
试开URL’https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/htmltools_0.5.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 361526 bytes (353 KB)
downloaded 353 KB

试开URL’https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/sass_0.4.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3642600 bytes (3.5 MB)
downloaded 3.5 MB

package ‘htmltools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘sass’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpekYODb\downloaded_packages
安装源码包‘bslib’, ‘shiny’, ‘treemap’

试开URL’https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/bslib_0.7.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 5125401 bytes (4.9 MB)
downloaded 4.9 MB

试开URL’https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/shiny_1.8.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3049516 bytes (2.9 MB)
downloaded 2.9 MB

试开URL’https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/treemap_2.4-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 158048 bytes (154 KB)
downloaded 154 KB

* installing *source* package 'bslib' ...
** package 'bslib' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  载入了名字空间'htmltools' 0.5.5，但需要的是>= 0.5.8
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
停止执行
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'bslib'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/bslib'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bslib’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'bslib' is not available for package 'shiny'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/shiny'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'shiny' is not available for package 'treemap'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/treemap'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘treemap’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpekYODb\downloaded_packages’
> library(treemap)
Error in library(treemap) : 不存在叫‘treemap’这个名字的程辑包


Package installation was almost certainly unsuccessful -- did any errors or warnings occur there?

Yes. I have put the warning and error in my question above. Could you help to see how to solve this?

I would say the very first message "Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding" is quite self-explanatory -- see here.
